# Need screen dimension with react nextjs but returning "Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server."

Tags: reactjs, next.js

i'm trying to get window dimensions but it's always returning "Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server."

```
const hasWindow = typeof window !== 'undefined';



function getWindowDimensions() {
    const width = hasWindow ? window.innerWidth : null;
    const height = hasWindow ? window.innerHeight : null;
    return {
      width,
      height,
    };
  }

  const [windowDimensions, setWindowDimensions] = useState(getWindowDimensions());

  useEffect(() => {
    if (hasWindow) {
      function handleResize() {
        setWindowDimensions(getWindowDimensions());
      }


    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
      return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
    }
  }, [hasWindow]);

setWidth(windowDimensions.width);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needed to use hooks, just moved setWidth inside the useEffect and it worked.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (hasWindow) {
      function handleResize() {
        setWindowDimensions(getWindowDimensions());
      }

      window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);

      setWidth(windowDimensions.width);
      return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
    }
  }, [hasWindow]);
```